# Particle Hair root jiggles away from emitter mesh during Hair Dynamics simulation

Tags: hair

Instead of the root point of the hair key staying fixed to it's original position, it moves away from the mesh, rendering the whole simulation unsuccessful.

Trying various settings with stiffness, weight, collision, did have an effect on the level of displacement, but it still isn't satisfactory

[Video example 1](https://mega.nz/file/C6JQRCQa#6U6pwsU3EIez7VcaLU2QyBSi7_Q2rhDGosFTFickX5w)

[Video example 2](https://mega.nz/file/Lj40RJJL#LsdvimbWobT0et1-26tZH2nJf7WC-LbjBb8BGzKBnJg)

[Blender file with particle hair mesh](https://mega.nz/file/jnZQ2BIQ#jKVD_KAokFfRAlQG-YNvcHddxlrkMlIny4BqHrm6AKM)

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.